# Display custom post categories as plan text

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, plaintext

I am using this code to display custom post categories hierarchicaly, everything is working till now great but what I want to achieve also is to display these categories as plain text (without `<a href="..."`). Can anyone help?

```
                  $taxonomy = 'produkte_kategorie'; // change this to your taxonomy
                  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( "fields" => "ids" ) );
                  if( $terms ) {
                    echo '<ul class="p-kategorie">';
                    $terms = trim( implode( ',', (array) $terms ), ' ,' );
                    wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $terms );
                    echo '</ul>';
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via the following function,

```
$terms = trim( implode( ',', (array) $terms ), ' ,' );
$categories = get_categories(array('include'=>$terms,'taxonomy'=>'produkte_kategorie'));

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->cat_name;
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this didn't worked for me but I made a solution with this code from wordpress codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

$taxonomy = 'category';

// Get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

// Separator between links.
$separator = ', ';

if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

```
$term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

$terms = wp_list_categories( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'style'    => 'none',
    'echo'     => false,
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'include'  => $term_ids
) );

$terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

// Display post categories.
echo  $terms;
```

Thanks a lot for your Feedback